# Model factory create function not working

Tags: magento2, blocks, model

I am learning how to develop a CRUD module in magento 2. I have develop a module in which database is created through my setup file. But I am not able to use model in Block.

For this I have created my model file:

```
namespace CompanyName\Hello\Model;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements TestInterface, \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'hello_test';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('CompanyName\Hello\Model\ResourceModel\Test');
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    public function loadByTitle($title){
        if(!$title){
            $title = $this->getTitle();
        }
        $id = $this->getResource()->loadByTitle($title);
        return $this->load($id);
    }
}
```

And I have create my Block file:

```
<?php

namespace CompanyName\Hello\Block;

class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_testFactory;
    protected $logger;
    public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            \CompanyName\Hello\Model\TestFactory $testFactory, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_testFactory = $testFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $test = $this->_testFactory->create();
        $this->logger->info('after create');
        $test->setTitle('magento');
        $test->save();
        $this->setTestModel($test);
    }
}
```

But I am getting a blank page without any error. Currently I am working in **Developer Mode**. If I remove this code then my page is visible correctly.

Need an Urgent help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please check on log & report folder

Comment: I have checked it, but not getting any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the Interface. You mention in you model `implements TestInterface`

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\Hello\Model;
interface TestInterface 
{

}
```

delete **var/generation** after that

Comment: I don't know anything about interface. Can you tell me wky we need to declare Interface?

Comment: @GauravAgrawal because you are using it `implements TestInterface` in you code check the magento module structure then you understand it